# Asp.net Keydown Event not always fired within GridView

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview

Within a griview (using IE), cells in one column are clickable (through gridview row command event) and once a cell is clicked it displays a hidden textbox (visible = false before the cell is clicked); users can enter text into the textbox and to allow saving changes made to the textbox users are told to press Tab key. 
The saving is done through using Javascript by checking keycode in keydown event, it simply checks when `keycode = 9 (Tab key) __doPostback('OnClick','SaveButton');` in codebehind `SaveButton` onclick event simply calls a store procedure to save the new text changes into database.

The problem I have is keydown event is not ALWAYS fired though it works most of the time. There seems to be no difference to the situation when it works and when it doesn't, so to me it's a bit random and I have to emphaise that it works 90% of the time.

Worth mentioning that when users click the cell to edit the textbox, gridview row updating event is fired first since I need to enable gridview row updating event not only for this column text changes but also for other columns data updating.

When everything 'works' after user pressing the Tab key, the event sequence is:

1. Gridview row updating
2. Keydown/SaveButton click
3. Gridview row updating

I don't understand what triggers the event 3 i.e. the second gridview row updating event though it doesn't do any harm to anything as it's after the text being saved into database. But when pressing Tab key doesn't work (text not saved) the second gridview row updating event is not fired; only the 1st row updating event is fired and textbox changes are lost reverting back to the original text.

I'm new to asp.net and hope someone can shred some light on this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out why GridView row updating event fired for the 2nd time, it's because AutoPost for the editable textbox being set to True.

silly me...